# Submitting form_with (or form _for) with nested resources is routing to wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm trying to submit a form a show method. No matter what I do it doesn't go to the correct controller and always routes back to the show method.  The issue is it should be going to the LeadsController create method, not the JobListingsController show method.  Here is my code.

routes

```
resources :job_listings do 
  resources :leads
end
```

job_listings_controller

```
class JobListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_listing, only: [:show, :update, :edit, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @job_listings = JobListing.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @job_listing = current_user.job_listings.build
  end

  def create
    @job_listing = current_user.job_listings.new(job_listing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job_listing.save
        format.html {redirect_to root_path}
      else
        format.js {render 'job_listings/new'}
      end
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  #...

  private

  #...

  def find_listing
    @job_listing = JobListing.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

leads_controller

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  include LeadsHelper
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]
  before_action :find_admins, only: [:create]
  before_action :find_job_listing, only: [:create, :new]

  def index
    @leads = Lead.joins(:job_listing).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @lead = Lead.new
  end

  def create 
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @lead.save
        send_emails_to_leads_admins
        set_cookie
        format.html {redirect_to root_path}
      else
        format.js {render 'leads/new'}
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def lead_params
    params.require(:lead).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :file, :phone, :job_listing_id)
  end

  #...

  def find_job_listing
    @job_listing = JobListing.find(params[:job_listing_id])
  end
end
```

form

```
<%= form_with( model: [@job_listing, Lead.new]) do |form| %>
```

I have done the correct associations, a Lead belongs_to a :job_listing and a Joblisting has_many :leads.

I have tried everything I could find, but no matter what I do its the same result. [View console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmcv2.png)

Any tips or advice would help!

Answer (score 0):

Check that your form is not embedded inside another form.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have changed that, but the Issue is it should be going to the LeadsController create method, not the JobListingsController show method.

Comment: The form might be defaulting to `get` method. Try specifying `form_with(model: [@job_listing, Lead.new], method: :post)` and see if that changes the action.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, It ended being that the form I rendered was inside of another form in the HTML. This is why it was not respecting were I was telling it to submit. Its working like a champ now!

Comment: Thanks for providing an update on what the problem actually was. I will update this answer for the benefit of other community members that have a similar issue.